# Sending multiple GET variables in URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to retrieve multiple $_GET variables within PHP. Javascript is sending the URL and it seems to have an issue with the '&' between variables.

One variable works:

```
 //JAVASCRIPT
 var price = "http://<site>/realtime/bittrex-realtime.php?symbol=LTC";

 //THE PHP END
 $coinSymbol = $_GET['symbol'];
 echo $coinSymbol

 OUTPUT: LTC
```

With two variables:

```
 //JAVASCRIPT
 var price = "http://<site>/realtime/bittrex-realtime.php?type=price&symbol=LTC";

 //THE PHP END
 $coinSymbol = $_GET['symbol'];
 $type = $_GET['type'];
 echo $coinSymbol
 echo $type

 OUTPUT: price
```

It just seems to ignore everything after the '&'. I know that the PHP end works fine because if I manually type the address into the browser, it prints both variables.

```
 http://<site>/realtime/bittrex-realtime.php?type=price&symbol=LTC

 OUTPUT ON THE PAGE
 priceLTC
```

Any ideas? It's driving me nuts - Thanks

**UPDATE - JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
refresh();

jQuery('#bittrex-price').load(price);

});

function refresh() {

   setTimeout( function() {
        //document.write(mintpalUrl);
        jQuery('#bittrex-price').fadeOut('slow').load(price).fadeIn('slow');

        refresh();

   }, 30000);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the javascript code that is submitting to your PHP script?

Comment: Where's the JS code that uses that `price` variable?

Comment: Tip: The proper tools for debugging in this situation are `var_dump` and `print_r`, e.g. `var_dump($_GET)`.

Comment: Could you try escaping your ampersand.  &amp; instead of &

Comment: @BrianDriscoll - I've added the Javascript/jQuery above. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelHays Have tried that, just tried again - Still no joy :(

Comment: Try adding this: echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; it will output what was in url

Comment: @Thomas It spits out what it should: type=price&symbol=LTC :/

Comment: Curious, you do have an closing semi-colon for `echo $coinSymbol` correct?

Comment: @Fred-ii- His code wouldn't run if he didn't.

Comment: @Thomas I just had to ask. When I see one line of code without it and it echoes, it will work. When I see 2 lines of code missing semi-colons, is when I start raising a brow. Doesn't hurt to ask ;) I take posted code for face value.

Comment: Trust me lol I know. I'm confused how it's fine in the query_String but not in $_GET.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes they are both semi-coloned, I modified it on here to simplify it a bit for you guys and forgot the type them - Good spot but not the problem :(

Comment: @Thomas Pleeeeeease help, haha I'm literally at my wits end :'( I laugh, I'm not really laughing, I'm dying inside lol. 15 hours I've been trying to get a few divs to auto update every few minutes! Sigh, I hate being crap at coding.

Comment: Did the answer below work? I have been trying to solve an issue in a program I'm working on for months, it has to do with the best way to do something...I know the pain lol

Comment: @thomas No I haven't been able to get it to work with that answer yet. I'm going to do some further research on the .load tomorrow as it seems like the right idea, just a slightly more complicated way of doing it. I'm absolutely baffled as to why PHP can't find the second GET var, we've established it's arriving on the plane... it just vanishes when it's time to get off. I know nothing about Javascript which really isn't helping. Sigh, glad you told me how to print the URL out mind, I had been searching for that also :)

Comment: I'd try doing a var_dump on $GLOBALS and see what you get. If you want, shoot me an email rot_natalicw--yahoo--com I'll be happy to help you one on one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the url and the data that you will be sending

```
var price = "http://<site>/realtime/bittrex-realtime.php";

function refresh() {

   var params = {type:'price', symbol: 'LTC'};

   setTimeout( function() {
        //document.write(mintpalUrl);
        jQuery('#bittrex-price').fadeOut('slow').load(price, params).fadeIn('slow');

        refresh();

   }, 30000);
}
```

And in your PHP use $_POST or you can do it like this

```
$coinSymbol = isset($_POST['symbol']) ? $_POST['symbol'] : $_GET['symbol'];
```

Refer to here for more information [jquery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: I can't get this to work :( - It's worth noting that the Javascript I've added above is fixed in the header & I'm creating the variables in the body. This is my first time working with Javascript so I'm not sure if that makes any difference? Thanks @andrex

Comment: @Ryan I'm confuse how did you manage to construct the url with the parameters in the first place?

Comment: I need to get several different bits of information from http://<site>/realtime/bittrex-realtime.php - The only way I could think to do it was to use $_GET variables to have the page display a different bit of information each time it was called. The URL is just manually typed in, I'm not constructing it with any concatenation...yet @andrex

Comment: Now why can't you get it to work? You are manually typing the url right.  For now instead using the url with the parameters in the load function, separate it like how I wrote it. Even if it's separated it will still be passed to the php side,  Also read more about the load function in the link.  There are examples there too.

Comment: I just can't see why the original method works with one variable but not 2 :/ - I've had a quick look at the link you've supplied, it looks beyond my knowledge at first glance, I'm not the most savvy coder. I'll spend some time researching the .load function tomorrow and see if I can find a simple explanation to get me from A > B- I've been trying to get this whole Javascript bit trying to run for about 15 hours straight - I'm done with it for today, I'm out. Thanks for your help, I'll do some research tomorrow

Comment: So you did try my suggestion? And it did work for you?

Comment: I have tried it, couldn't get it to work exactly as you've done it. I'll try again tomorrow when my heads not so worn out. I think you're on the right track though. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61645/discussion-between-andrex-and-ryan).